# How to box  verbatim to prevent page break?

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, verbatim

If I try

```
\mbox{
  \begin{verbatim}
    Some looooong text...
  \end{verbatim}
}
```

Then some compilation errors occur.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several packages on [ctan](http://www.ctan.org) that offer enhanced verbatim features. In particular, [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb) provides a simple mechanism to prevent page breaks.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[samepage=true]
Some looooong text...
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb) also provides the `BVerbatim` environment which puts verbatim material into a box.

Answer (score 16):

Ian Thompson shows how to use `fancyvrb` to prevent page breaking. If you still want to know how to put `verbatim` in a box, see below:

1) You can put it in a `minipage` environment:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
blah blah
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

It is enough if you just want to prevent page breaks.

2) You cannot put `verbatim` in the argument of `\parbox`, `\mbox`, `\makebox`, or `\fbox`. That's because `verbatim` is vertical material (that only `minipage` and `\parbox` can be used), and it changes category codes heavily (that you can't use it in a argument). You can, when necessary, use `lrbox` environment to save the box, for future use:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newsavebox{\verbbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
blah blah
blah blah
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\fbox{\usebox{\verbbox}}

\end{document}
```

BTW, it is also easier to use `fancyvrb` to save the `verbatim` environment.

Answer (score 2):

[TH](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/647/th) posted at http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2011/01/better-mbox-and-fbox.html about the reason for `\verb` not being available in `\mbox` (its "argument[...] cannot change category codes") and how to cure that: be redefining `\mbox`:

```
\def\bettermbox{\leavevmode\hbox}
```

[*I'm not sure whether it would be OK to cite the whole post, thus please follow the link yourself. @TH: Could you either add an own answer or grant the right for citing your whole post here?*]

That said, I would not recommend using an `\mbox` to solve your page-break-problem. The answer of Ian Thompson is better suited for that purpose.