# Verbatim has different margins than BVerbatim

Tags: spacing, verbatim

I am changing some `Verbatim` blocks to `BVerbatim` to avoid page breaks in the middle of some short source code examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[scaled=.73]{beramono}
\fvset{baselinestretch=0.94}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip = 6pt
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,%
  fancyvrb=true,%
}

\begin{document}

Before using Verbatim.

\begin{Verbatim}
foo
bar
\end{Verbatim}

After using Verbatim. \\ Before using BVerbatim.

\begin{BVerbatim}
foo
bar
\end{BVerbatim}

After using BVerbatim.

\end{document}
```

However, these two have different margin settings. `BVerbatim` has less spacing before and after the code block:

[image]

How can I adjust `BVerbatim` here so that it looks like `Verbatim`?

Comment: Using `\begin{Verbatim}[samepage=true]`, as described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16923/how-to-box-verbatim-to-prevent-page-break#16926), is an alternative which doesn't alter the spacing. I am still curious if one can configure `BVerbatim` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`Verbatim` uses an own paragraph for its contents, but `BVerbatim` not. 
You can use:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{BVerbatim}{BVerbatim}{formatcom=\bigskip}
```

But there is no option to add vertical space at the end.  You have to rewrite `\endBVerbatim` or to add `\par`.

Comment: I don't get the same vertical spacing in the end, neither with `\endBVerbatim` nor with an additional `\par`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new environment using BVerbatim as a basis.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[scaled=.73]{beramono}    
\fvset{baselinestretch=0.94}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip = 6pt
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,%
  fancyvrb=true,%
}

\newenvironment{myBVerbatim}%
{\bigskip\VerbatimEnvironment
\begin{BVerbatim}}
{\end{BVerbatim}%
\bigskip}

\begin{document}

Before using Verbatim.

\begin{Verbatim}
foo
bar
\end{Verbatim}

After using Verbatim. \\ Before using BVerbatim.

\begin{BVerbatim}
foo
bar
\end{BVerbatim}

After using BVerbatim. \\ Before using myBVerbatim

\begin{myBVerbatim}
foo
bar
\end{myBVerbatim}

After using myBVerbatim

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: myBVerbatim environment]